# How to access a variable from another JS file, after a function has been loaded and executed?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have an HTML file (django template) that loads a separate JS file.
In this JS file I have an event listener that waits for an element in the HTML to be loaded and then writes some data into a list.

HTML file:

```
<script src={% static 'file.js' %}></script>
<script> 
  //access data?
</script>
```

JS file:

```
var data = [];
obj.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //do stuff
  data  = ...
}
```

How can I now get access to this data inside my HTML and make sure to wait for the event listener to finish before accessing it?

I tried using the export/import key words, but obviously it doesn't wait for the function and I just get an empty list:

JS file

```
data = [];
export default data;
obj.addEventListener('load', function(){...}
```

HTML file

```
<script type="module" src={% static 'file.js' %}></script>
<script type="module"> 
  import data from "{% static 'file.js' %}"
  console.log(data)
</script>
```

I also tried using an event listener in the HTML file without success:

```
<script type="module">
  import data from "{% static 'js/conf-lab.js' %}"

  var oScript = document.createElement('script');
  oScript.src = '{% static 'file.js' %}';
  oScript.type = 'module';
  oScript.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(oScript);
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `postMessage` if you can modify both parts? If there’s an event handler that populates the data there’s not that many ways to wait for that to happen.

Comment: *"and make sure to wait for the event listener to finish"* - Whatever operation you want to perform after the event listener, invoke that operation in the last line of the event listener?  No combination of modules and exports will change the fact that you can't use data before it exists.

Comment: Oh yeah that would be the simplest solution, haven't thought of just writing the code in the event listener, because I don't think I can use my django-{{form}} tags inside the separate JS file, but I guess I just have to use vanilla js-forms instead of these simple django tags.